# Safari webkit build/revision

Tags: safari, webkit

How can I check which revision (svn revision) of webkit is used in a specific Safari binary? For example, I'd like to know which revision is used in the newest Safari on Mac (snow leopard 10.6.7).

User-agent doesn't provide this information :(

Answer (score 3):

You can get an approximation using the version tag of Webkit as it appears in User-Agent :

Let's take for example the following user-agent :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2

Webkit version is advertised here as `537.13+`. This version tag is generated from following source file :

https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/Configurations/Version.xcconfig

You could then take a look at which SVN revisions embeded this specifig version tag.